# Radtrelist binding

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, telerik

I am trying to bind the simple employee table to Radtreelist but it shoes only columns not data.
source view-->

following is code that i used to bind data to Radtreelist control

```
void binddata()
{
    cn = new 
      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
    strquery = "select Emp_Id,Emp_Name,Emp_Salary,DeptID from Employee";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(strquery, cn);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    RadTreeList1.DataSource = dt;
    RadTreeList1.DataBind();


}
```

and table having  `field Emp_Id,Emp_Name,Emp_Salary,DeptID`

so when i run the application it shoes only column of database
[image: Image when i run the application]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the .aspx code with Radtreelist definition

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not setting the **DataKeyNames** and **ParentDataKeyNames** properties of the RadTreeList

Check the demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/databinding/variousdatasources/defaultcs.aspx).